# Move element backward in a List using Collections.rotate() in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have an ArrayList as mentioned below (My Code Snippet).

My List elements are in this order initially - *("Periodic", "Multiple", "Single", "Subsequent", "Consecutive").*

After applying **Collections.rotate()** on my List elements the modified List should look like -

*("Periodic", "Subsequent", "Multiple", "Single", "Consecutive")*.

Element "Subsequent" needs to be moved backward to the 1st index element in the List which is "Multiple", so that the element at 1st index will be pushed down to the 2nd index after rotating.

When I tried using **Collections.rotate()**, it throws an Exception.

> **IllegalArgumentException** **"fromIndex > toIndex"**.

I researched and understood the error, **toIndex** should always be greater than or equal to **fromIndex**, but I could not quite figure out how to modify my code snippet in order to achieve what I need.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Isn't it possible to move an element backward in a List using **rotate()** method?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Periodic", "Multiple", "Single", "Subsequent", "Consecutive"));
       for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int indexOfSubName = 0;
            int indexOfMultipleName = 0;

            String name = list.get(i);

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Subsequent")) {
                indexOfSubName = list.indexOf(name);

            }

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Multiple")) {
                int indexOfMultipleName = list.indexOf(name);
            }
           Collections.rotate(list.subList(indexOfSubName , indexOfMultipleName ), 1);
        }
```

Comment: do you mean just swapping n-1 with 1st element?

Comment: I'm sorry I have edited my question. I did not mean to swap n-1 with 1st element, I meant to move n-1 element to the 1st index position so that the element at 1st index will be pushed down to the 2nd index after rotating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- You are trying to get sublist from 3 to 1 which should be vice versa. So you could check min and max and then try to get sublist.
- Your sublist call will bring you element say from index 1 to n-1 i.e. if you pass 3, you will get just two elements i.e. index 1 and 2 and not the third one. See this [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) for details. You could do something like:

  ```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Periodic", "Multiple", "Single", "Subsequent", "Consecutive"));
  int indexOfSubName = 0;
  int indexOfMultipleName = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      String name = list.get(i);
      if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Subsequent")) {
          indexOfSubName = list.indexOf(name);
      }
      if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Multiple")) {
          indexOfMultipleName = list.indexOf(name);
      }
  }
  int min = Math.min(indexOfMultipleName, indexOfSubName);
  int max = Math.max(indexOfMultipleName, indexOfSubName);
  Collections.rotate(list.subList(min, max+1), 1);
  System.out.println(list);
  ```

if you run this, you will get output as what you need:

```
[Periodic, Subsequent, Multiple, Single, Consecutive]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for an insightful information. Now works as expected.

Comment: Just a clarification, if the distance is positive (1) then element at max+1 will be moved to min right? and if the distance is negative (-1) then element at min will be moved to max+1 right? I did not quite get the hang of rotate() method, would be of great help if you could shed some light on this.

Comment: so if your elements are a,b,c and if your distance is 1, then output would be c,a,b (right shift), while if was negative then it would be a left shift b,c,a.

Answer (score 3):

Almas is correct but the code can be a bit more concise:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Periodic", "Multiple", "Single", "Subsequent", "Consecutive"));
    System.out.format("Before: %s%n", list);
    int indexOfSubName = list.indexOf("Subsequent");
    int indexOfMultipleName = list.indexOf("Multiple");
    int min = Math.min(indexOfMultipleName, indexOfSubName);
    int max = Math.max(indexOfMultipleName, indexOfSubName);
    int distance = 1; // Can be 1 or -2
    Collections.rotate(list.subList(min, max + 1), distance);
    System.out.format("After: %s%n", list);
```

You can rotate the sublist 1 distance forward or -2 distance backward for the same effect.

Comment: for me it's distance 1 forward and -1 backward

Answer (score 0):

actually list does it automatically when adding an item to a certain index, no need to use rotate:

```
//                                                                   (.) -----------------> (.)
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Periodic", "Multiple", "Single", "Subsequent", "Consecutive"));
    list.remove("Multiple");
    int newPosition = 3;
    list.add(newPosition, "Multiple");
    System.out.println(list);
    //                                                   (.) <------------------ (.)
    list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Periodic", "Multiple", "Single", "Subsequent", "Consecutive"));
    list.remove("Subsequent");
    newPosition = 1;
    list.add(newPosition, "Subsequent");
    System.out.println(list);
```

output:

```
[Periodic, Single, Subsequent, Multiple, Consecutive]
[Periodic, Subsequent, Multiple, Single, Consecutive]
```